# How to add compound node in a D3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I'm adding nodes to a force layout graph like this:

```
var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
    .call(force.drag);
```

Is there a way to add compound SVG elements as nodes? I.e. I want to add a hyperlink for each circle, so I'd need something like this:

`<a href="whatever.com"><circle ...></circle></a>`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Creating a "compound" element is as simple as appending one or more children to another element.  In your example, you want to bind your data to a selection of `<a>` elements, and give each `<a>` a single `<circle>` child.

First of all, you need to select `"a.node"` instead of `"circle.node"`.  This is because your hyperlinks are going to be the parent elements.  If there isn't an obvious parent element, and you just want to add multiple elements for each datum, use `<g>`, SVG's group element.

Then, you want to append one `<a>` element to each node in the entering selection.  This creates your hyperlinks.  After setting each hyperlink's attributes, you want to give it a `<circle>` child.  Simple: just call `.append("circle")`.

```
var node = vis.selectAll("a.node")
    .data(nodes);

// The entering selection: create the new <a> elements here.
// These elements are automatically part of the update selection in "node".
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("a")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://whatever.com")
    .call(force.drag);

// Appends a new <circle> element to each element in nodeEnter.
nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })

node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Remember that D3 primarily operates on *selections* of nodes.  So calling `.append()` on the entering *selection* means that each node in the selection gets a new child.  Powerful stuff!

One more thing: SVG has [its own `<a>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links), which is what I was referring to above. This is different from the HTML one! Typically, you only use SVG elements with SVG, and HTML with HTML.

*Thanks to @mbostock for suggesting that I clarify the variable naming.*

Comment: Although I understand why this works for creation, doesnt it break on updating? Since append() merges the enter and update selections, wont it append a new circle to old nodes every time update is called?

Comment: I've updated the example to make it clearer.  selection.append doesn't *merge* any selections, but selection.enter().append automatically adds the elements to the update selection.  My original example had vis.selectAll(…).data(…).enter().append(…).  This only appends elements to the entering selection, so no problem there; the key point is that the entering selection initially only contains placeholders for *new* elements that don't exist yet.

Answer (score 11):

Reply to Jason Davies (since stackoverflow limits the length of reply comments…): Excellent answer. Be careful with the method chaining, though; typically you want `node` to refer to the outer anchor element rather than the inner circle element. So I'd recommend a small variation:

```
var node = vis.selectAll("a.node")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("a")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://whatever.com")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); });
```

I've also replaced the circle's cx and cy attributes with a transform on the containing anchor element; either one will work. You can treat svg:a elements as svg:g (both are containers), which is nice if you want to add labels later.

Comment: Thanks! I've modified the first example slightly (removed `var node = ` as it's redundant and potentially confusing as you point out). The second example with variables is consistent with yours, although I agree the transform is probably more useful.